# how to get attribute of a nested child element

Tags: javascript

I want to retrieve a specific attribute value from inside nested child nodes. what is the best way to do this?

Below code works, but I will not know the number of child nodes every time.

```
 parent.childNodes[0].childNodes[0].childNodes[0].getAttribute('placeholder');
```

Comment: You can check the length of child nodes and use a loop

Comment: @Hkachhia, If we retrieve child nodes, we will get list of child nodes for the parent. But here, it is nested child of first child node.

Comment: I think you need some kind of recursion. However, assuming that you are working with nodes/elements, can you show us some example and what you want to achieve? Instead of combing through arbitrary levels of child nodes, what about just selecting the first descendant that has the `placeholder` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this with a recursive function.
I made this one for solving the issue.

```js
function getNestedAttribute(node, attrib) {
  // this is not really eficient but I forced it to use childnodes
  if (node.childNodes.length && node.children.length) {
    node.childNodes.forEach((child) => {
     if (child.nodeName === "#text") return;
       return getNestedAttribute(child, attrib);
      });
    }
    else {
      let attr = node.getAttribute(attrib) || null;
      if (!attr) return;
      console.log(`[${attrib}]`, attr, {
        info: {
          node,
          attrib,
        },
      });
    }
}
```

And here you have a working solution=)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Recursive Placeholder</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul id="parent">
      <li>
        <ul>
          <li><input type="text" placeholder="hi there" /></li>
          <li><input type="text" placeholder="hola" /></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <button type="button" onclick="getPlaceholder()">Get Placeholder</button>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div>
          <div>
            <button type="button" onclick="getAllTypes()">Get Types</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      function getPlaceholder() {
        const parent = document.getElementById("parent");
        getNestedAttribute(parent, "placeholder");
      }

      function getNestedAttribute(node, attrib) {
        if (node.childNodes.length && node.children.length) {
          node.childNodes.forEach((child) => {
            if (child.nodeName === "#text") return;
            return getNestedAttribute(child, attrib);
          });
        } else {
          let attr = node.getAttribute(attrib) || null;
          if (!attr) return;
          console.log(`[${attrib}]`, attr, {
            info: {
              node,
              attrib,
            },
          });
        }
      }

      // Extra:
      function getAllTypes() {
        getNestedAttribute(document.body, "type");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```